# How to use Flash messages in fat free framework?

Tags: php, session-variables, fat-free-framework

I am trying to make an small app so I have choosen Fat Free Framework. I need to show some messages based on successful or error. Suppose if I want to add an user then if successfully added show message that user has been added successfully or if not show error message that user cannot be added. I cannot figure it out. Here is my UsersController code

```
 public function index(){
     $user = new User($this->db);
     $this->f3->set('users',$user->all());
     //there should be a way to decide if its error message or success and after display, 
     //it shouldn't be displayed again for the same task.
     //or may be it should be check in view file, I don't know where is the correct place
     // to do it
     $this->f3->set('page_head','User List');
     $this->f3->set('view','users/list.htm');
```

}

```
  public function create(){
    if($this->f3->exists('POST.create')){
    $user = new User($this->db);
    $user->add();
    //set session here to show in view file after redirect to list page
    $this->f3->reroute('/users');
   } else{
    $this->f3->set('page_head','Create User');
    $this->f3->set('view','users/create.htm');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My flash messages controller looks like this: https://github.com/ikkez/f3-flash/blob/master/lib/flash.php

To set a message i do:

```
if ($this->resource->updateProperty(array('_id = ?', $params['id']), 'published', true)) {
  \Flash::instance()->addMessage('Your post was published. Hurray!', 'success');
} else {
  \Flash::instance()->addMessage('This Post ID was not found', 'danger');
}
$f3->reroute('/admin/post');
```

To render the messages i include this template in my layout https://github.com/ikkez/fabulog/blob/master/app/ui/templates/alert.html which calls a function that dumps and clears all messages, so they will only be displayed once. You can also use the SESSION in a template token like `{{@SESSION.flash}}` and use it for `<repeat>` in the template.

Comment: very nice @ikkez . how about adding this to the list of plugins ? :-P

Comment: I placed this class under helper and added namespace `namespace Helper;` in flash.php then in my controller I called this way:`\Helper\Flash::instance()->addMessage("Failed to apply the action: $action.", 'danger');` class FlashMessage also not found :)

Comment: the class isn't named FlashMessage anymore.. it's just Flash

Comment: @ikkez That's great but I have a question. Message correctly appears but doesn't desappear if I click the cross. Is there anything special to do (Firefox).

Comment: thats probably a bootstrap framework feature and nothing related to the flash plugin here. see twitter bootstrap

Comment: Absolute **BEST** flash message controller I've found. Thank you!